# Any good alternative for ASP.NET validation controls?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

Is there easy to integrate ASP.NET with jQuery form validation plugin or any other JS framework to replace standard ASP.NET client validation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the [Validation Engine](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) from Position Absolute to just be that, Absolutely awesome! :). I have an [article](http://www.pieterg.com/post/2010/03/18/Good-looking-validation-with-ASPNET-MVC-20-Custom-Validation.aspx) on how to include it in ASP.NET MVC and in ASP.NET, you could just pass it the generated form id.

Comment: More or less what i need. Will look into...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[are you referring to this?](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: Hard to implement, it failed in past to integrate with ASP.NET server validation.
Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xVal for WebForms.](http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The only thing i'm afraid about using it that xVal were not updated since August 2009 with only alpha release ...
Do you use this in production ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ValidationControls with [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx).